# Python - IndexError: list index out of range - For loop / While loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop, while-loop

I have this string:

```
string="R$ 35.0123. "
```

I want to clean that, taking that final dot and that space in the end out. Making it look like this:

```
string:"R$ 35.0123"
```

I'm trying to use this:

```
while string[-1].isdigit()==False:
      string=string[:-1]
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The weird thing is that I'm running this inside a for loop and if the looped list has only one item, it works fine. If the list has two items, this problem happens.

Any ideas?
Merry xmas for you all.

**FULL CODE BELOW**
(the string is the variable "valor")

```
if CNPJ in page:
    CNPJloc=[]
    for i in (re.finditer(CNPJ,page)):
        CNPJloc.append(i.start())

    for i in CNPJloc:
        CNPJposition=i
        beg_string=["aviao"]
        end_string="sicon"
        for i in beg_string:
            if i in lower_page[CNPJposition-200:]:
                beg_string=i                
                extrato_de_contrato=page[lower_page.rfind(beg_string,0,CNPJposition):lower_page.find(end_string,CNPJposition)]
                lower_extrato=extrato_de_contrato.lower()
                def valor():
                    valor=["valor do contrato:","valor:"]
                    for i in valor:
                        if i in lower_extrato:
                            valor=extrato_de_contrato[lower_extrato.rfind(i)+len(i):lower_extrato.find("fonte",lower_extrato.rfind(i))]
                        while valor[-1].isdigit()==False:
                            valor=valor[:-1]
                    print("Valor Total: ", valor)
                    return valor
                valor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has functionality built in to do this with `rstrip`

```
string.rstrip('. ')
```

Output

```
'R$ 35.0123'
```

Sounds like you just need to remove the last dot and everything after that. Use regex

```
import re
re.sub('(\.[^.]*)$', '', string)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for that. The problem is that sometimes it might be ". ", other times might be only "." and other times can be " . xzxzx".

Comment: Also see [**`str.rsplit`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with `sep='.'` and `maxsplit=1`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably encountering a string that doesn't follow your format, and contain no digits.

Try securing your loop by adding a `len(x) > 0` indicator:

```
while len(string) > 0 and not string[-1].isdigit():
     del string[-1]
```

---

If you just want to extract the integer from you string, I would suggest regex:

```
import re
matches = re.findall('\d+\.?\d*', string)
string = int(matches[0]) if len(matches) > 0 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... the good old indentation error:

Instead of:

```
            def valor():
                valor=["valor do contrato:","valor:"]
                for i in valor:
                    if i in lower_extrato:
                        valor=extrato_de_contrato[lower_extrato.rfind(i)+len(i):lower_extrato.find("fonte",lower_extrato.rfind(i))]
                    while valor[-1].isdigit()==False:
                        valor=valor[:-1]
```

It should go like:

```
            def valor():
                valor=["valor do contrato:","valor:"]
                for i in valor:
                    if i in lower_extrato:
                        valor=extrato_de_contrato[lower_extrato.rfind(i)+len(i):lower_extrato.find("fonte",lower_extrato.rfind(i))]
                    --> while valor[-1].isdigit()==False:
                    -->     valor=valor[:-1]
```